# Control property is Collection. How to add change event when the collection changes?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I'm using a 3rd party control and one of it's property is an object collection. I would like to launch a change event when this collection changes. I've read about BindingList, but I don't know how-to (if possible) override the type of the 3rd party control property. Any clue?

Comment: Some basic info are required: which is collection base class? Can you derive from it and use derived class?

Comment: It's a custom class that implements IEnumerable. I can derive from it, but the control will still have the original custom type as a property.

Comment: It implements IEnumerable but it doesn't derive, for example, from Collection<T>? Then it depends what they exposed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not under your control, because it's 3rd party code, you cannot override it. Unless the control offers this capability.

You should check if the control offers an event of it's own, otherwise, looking at it as a black box, all you can do is polling (checking at a given interval of time the collection, with a timer)